# How fetch local data with axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I want my data from my JSON file (crew.json) but i can't receive it :

```
const [apiNews, setApiNews] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  
    const apiNews = await axios.create({baseURL:
      `http://localhost:3000/`, headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      }}) 
      apiNews.get('../../micro-components/Api/crew.json')
 
    setApiNews(apiNews.data);
 
  console.log("APIHEADER", apiNews.data)
       
}
fetchData(apiNews);
  }, [])
```

Did you know why ? ... I've got a 404 but the '../../micro-components/Api/crew.json' is the correct way ...

Comment: If it's a local file, and assuming you're using something like `create-react-app`, then you could just do an `import` statement at the top of your file, no need to `fetch` anything.

Comment: Yes of course but i need to use axios because after, that will be on API server...

Comment: Then you should run an API server, or serve up that file with your dev server during development. That path will basically say "Go up 2 directories from where my application loaded, and look for micro-components/Api/crew.json". If your app is served out of https://localhost:3000/ in development, then it basically is going to ask your dev server for https://localhost:3000/micro-components/Api/crew.json.

Comment: Your `baseURL` (`http://localhost:3000`) and your `path` (`.../.../micro-components/Api/crew.json`) will produce an incorrect `URL`, so you need to figure out what the appropriate `URL` is when this file is being served from your development server. Otherwise, just use something like `json-server` to spin up a quick `API` server and serve your data that way - https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be `await`ing for `axios.create`, instead move `await` next to `apiNews.get`.

Answer (score 1):

If something is in src code you should be importing it like

```
import data from '../../micro-components/Api.crew.json';
```

In that case you would avoid this whole thing.

If you really want to fetch data you can't do it from the src directory, but you can query the public directory like so

**Assuming crew.json is at `/my-app/public/crew.json`**

```
const [apiNews, setApiNews] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get('crew.json');
        setApiNews(data);
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

I would also say to do this because it means you don't have to

More info here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: my data file is at src/micro-components/Api/crew.json. But it's style doesn't work. I try in public folder but that's doesn't work too ... Always have a 404 errors

Comment: What do you mean by "it's style doesn't work"?

Are you using Create React App?